# How can I display another Project's issues in my current Sprint in Jira?

Tags: jira

### Context:

A large , enterprise level Programme which has many teams and a pipeline of working with both software and infrastructure including migration and decommissioning.

### Teams Affected

An upstream team gathers requirements from customers about applications and ensures that customers can either self-serve or move into one of two delivery tracks.  They author user stories, ensure firm acceptance criteria and define patterns and business outcomes.

A dedicated Feature Team then take those User Stories and deliver them with the upstream team attending the  Sprint Review to take custody of the delivery.

### Tools

Both teams use Jira and have mature user story processes

### Requirement

As the SM for the Feature Team I want to be able to take User Stories from the Upstream Team, from their backlog, and show them in our Sprint without moving them directly between backlogs.

### Solutions tried

- Bulk moving stories to the Feature Team backlog/project and then back to the Upstream Team upon completion (not ideal / unwieldy / loss of golden thread)
- Tagging stories with a manual tag showing the Feature Team Sprint (not ideal as it does not feed into the Jira reporting metrics.  It is just a tag).
- Editing the "Sprint" field in the User Story to show the Sprint that the story has been pulled into

### Summary

Two projects.  Two backlogs.  Team A do a portion of the stories for Team B  and pull them into their Sprint but the stories do not show up in the Jira Sprint, in the Burndown or the Sprint Report pages.

### Caveat

I am looking for a Jira answer.  Please don't respond with Organizational changes or other such critiques of the Programme delivery as much as you may want to.  It is nothing that has not been debated at length in a Programme of 250+ people. Apologies if that sounds curt but this forum has a tendency to drop straight into coaching mode and skirt the actual question.

Comment: Are both teams running their own instance/license of JIRA, or do they share one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that both Teams are sharing a single instance of JIRA Software.

If this is the case, then you should be able to simply [modify the filter query of your Scrum board](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/configuring-a-board). Just go to the board configuration screen (either through Board->Configure or Agile->Manage Boards->your board) then click 'Edit Filter Query', edit your query, then save it.

This works because, while it *looks* by default as if each Project has its own Board and the connection is incontrovertible, that's not actually the case. In practice, each Board represents simply a JQL issues filter, which, by default, will be something like "project = SP1 ORDER BY Rank ASC", where SP1 is the code identifier for your project (let's call it Scrum Project 1).

So all you'd need to do is change the filter to incorporate both projects. The JQL would then look something akin to "project = SP1 OR project = SP2 ORDER BY Rank ASC". At which point, any issues created for *both* project would show up in your Backlog (and, consequentially, would be available for inclusion in your Sprint). If you do this, one additional configuration change you may wish to make is to include 'Project' in the Card layout. This will cause the Board to show what Project each card belongs to on each card.

Note that, when you *create* an issue, it will be created for your current project, even if it's set up to show on both Boards. While Boards can be created irrespective of projects, issues cannot.

Comment: Disclaimer: I've only actually tried this on JIRA Agile, not JIRA Software, but given that Atlassian hasn't updated the documentation to show anything different for JIRA Software, I'd imagine it should still work.

Comment: Many many thanks Sarov.  I will run it today.